# Can ARIMAX covariates be lagged?

Tags: time-series, arima, lags, armax

I read that the ARIMAX is a composition of the Box-Jenkins approach and structural models. The X represents the structural part of the ARIMAX. Can the covariates in X be lagged, or are these meant to be at time 't'?

Comment: They can be lagged, no problem there.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Richard.